# Showing that the zeta function does not vanish on $Re(z)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, zeta-functions

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway that I am stuck at. I managed to solve 7 and (a) and (b) of 8. However I cannot show (c). Also I cannot see how to conclude (d) from using (c). Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have to use your answer for c to prove d?

Comment: (c) follows from (b), if you use $3+4\cos x+ \cos 2x=2(\cos x+1)^2\ge0$.

Comment: @aleden Then is there another way? Could you show me?

Comment: There is no other way. The argument is explained [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch). If your book doesn't give more details, then find some better ones.